# Is there an example of reducible compact 3-manifold with boundary that has no embedded incompressible two-sided surface?

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology, manifolds-with-boundary, compact-manifolds

There is a theorem stating that for irreducible compact manifolds with non-empty boundary there always exists such an embedded surface and I'm trying to understand why the irreducibility condition matters. May be some kind of connected sum would work as a counterexample?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider for instance, $B^3$.